# jquery if statement not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I was writing a very simple function but can't get the if statement to work correctly.

```
$("#supplyRequestTextbox-clients").live("blur", function() {
    var textboxValue = $(this).val().replace(/\d+/g, '').replace(" ", "");
    if (textboxValue == "NO ACCOUNT") {
        $(".controlBarTextboxNoAccount").fadeIn("fast");
    }
});
```

The value in the input #supplyRequestTextbox-clients represents a client and is organized like this:
id# FirstName LastName email phone
An example: 000001 John Doe johndoe@johndoe.com 123-456-7890

When no account is found, the string appears exactly like this:
000906 NO ACCOUNT

In my function I strip the digits and first space, then check to see if it works in my if statement.  I have alerted textboxValue and it is passing correctly, but no matter that textboxValue is, the if statement never fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the if condition to:

```
if(textboxValue.indexOf("NO ACCOUNT") !== -1)
```

`indexOf("NO ACCOUNT")` finds `"NO ACCOUNT"` within `textboxValue`, if it can't find it `-1` is returned. So this will be true if `"NO ACCOUNT"` is anywhere in your string.

Comment: YES!  Thank you, this worked perfectly.  I can't believe I didn't try something like this earlier, been staring at it too long.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @radleybobins No worries, happens to everyone :) 

A small issue I just thought of: if some nasty user enters `NO ACCOUNT` as their name for whatever reason, it might cause problems. But that seems quite unlikely...

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` for comparisons. You are assigning a truthy value, so the statement always fires.

Comment: yes, i can't believe I missed that.  now the if statement never fires, though, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there are no more spaces in the value? Have you tried not replacing the digits and space and just checking for `000906 NO ACCOUNT`?

Comment: I like where you head is at, but there are multiple id numbers depending on which school I am working with...so it could be  000907 or 000908, i'd like to keep the maintenance to a minimum when I add extra schools, so I don't want to add an extra OR each time I add a school, i'd rather just strip the id number off

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` condition to

```
if (textboxValue == "NO ACCOUNT")
```

If you do

```
if (textboxValue = "NO ACCOUNT")
```

You're actually assigning `"NO ACCOUNT"` to `textboxValue` and evaluating the result as bool.

Comment: so now it never works, no matter what textboxValue is, any ideas?

Comment: @radleybobins: You're getting rid of the spaces as well, so it's probably like `NOACCOUNT`. See what the value of the textbox actually is.

Comment: @blender when I alert textboxValue or append it into a testing box it appears correctly with the proper spaces.  The first space only is removed.

Comment: @radleybobins: please see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbyXf/). Your code now should work unless there is something else you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$("#supplyRequestTextbox-clients").live("blur", function() {
    var textboxValue = $(this).val().replace(/\d+/g, '').replace(" ", "");

    // check what textboxValue evaluates to:
    alert(textboxValue);

if (textboxValue == "NO ACCOUNT") {
    $(".controlBarTextboxNoAccount").fadeIn("fast");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `==` for comparisons as Kolink suggest.
2. You are replacing `" "` with `""`, IE. removing all spaces so your if statement will never return true.